# How can I use this code?

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm trying to get this code to work in Drupal 7.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#sample").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor:'#f00'},1000); }).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor:'#ccc'},1000);
  });       

});
```

For some reason, when I paste it into the front--page.tpl template, it doesn't work.

I've also tried including a JavaScript file into the template.php file.

Comment: Drupal modules should use Drupal behaviors, in such cases. I am not clear what you mean by pasting JavaScript code in a template file, and why you would not put the code in a JavaScript file.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery in D7 is in noConflict mode. You need to use jQuery instead of $, or a closure.
See http://drupal.org/node/171213

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! I read through it and came up with the following: `(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".box_teaser").mouseover(function() {
         $(this).animate({ backgroundColor:'#f00'},1000);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor:'#ccc'},1000);
    });   
  });
}(jQuery));`     Its still not working tho. The .js file is in the header when I view source, tried it in a static pace and it was working :(.

Comment: You have an error at the end its })(jQuery);  not }(jQuery));

Comment: @Peter Use jQuery instead of $ (see http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2012/05/about-jquery-usage-in-drupal.html)

Answer (score 1):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality. (For example, width,
>   height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be.)

The .css() function doesn't queue behind running animations, it's instantaneous.

To match the behaviour that you're after, you'd need to do the following:

```
(function($) { 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".box_teaser").mouseouver(function() {
      var p = $(".box_teaser").css("background-color", "yellow");
      p.hide(1500).show(1500);
      p.queue(function() {
        p.css("background-color", "red");
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

The .queue() function waits for running animations to run out and then fires whatever is in the function supplied.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I'm kinda new to programming etc., so I really appreciate your help. Ok, so I copied your script into a script.js, added it in my template file (I can see it in the <head> when I view source). It's still not working. The box should be yellow by now and "fade" to red in 1,5 sec, correct ?

Comment: yes, thats what it should do.   Also in front--page.tpl, add this line drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/js/my-new-js-file.js').  Then create /js/my-new-js-file.js and put your code in there.   This will help with debugging.   Also use firebug, with the console enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Or try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  /* your function inside here */
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try in this way: create your script example.js that have this code for example:

```
**var $ob= jQuery.noconflict();
$ob(function(){
```

$ob("a").fadeOut();
});**

Comment: where are you invoking jQuery.noconflict();  This is a no,no just wrap in in ({ })(jQuery);   Plus fadeOut is not what Peter is trying to do